# 500 remote exception while Process A try to access remote object from Process B connected via .NET remoting.(Client/server in the same machine)

Tags: c#, http, .net-remoting, remoteexception

I have a product with architecture that there are two processes . say Process A and Process B.

Process A is the main process calling Process B to provide some specific values.
Process B is running on port xxxx.
Process A makes a call to Process B (with request). Process B receives the request and makes a proper response but that response never go to Process A. We get a 500 Remote exception in "Charles Web debugging" as a response from Process B.

```
    <system.runtime.remoting>
      <application>
         <service>
            <wellknown type="Some name of the class".
                       mode="Singleton" 
                       objectUri="ClassName" />
         </service>
         <channels>
            <channel ref="http" port="123456" />
         </channels>
      </application>
   </system.runtime.remoting>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
   </startup>
```

I have checked all the networking, proxies but  couldn't find any issue. Independently Process A and process B not giving any errors.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could elaborate on what you are using for communication.  Is this Remoting? WCF? Raw Sockets?

Comment: It is a singleton class acessed via remoting. Hosted on "xxxx" http port.
<system.runtime.remoting>
      <application>
         <service>
            <wellknown type="Some name of the class".
                       mode="Singleton" 
                       objectUri="ClassName" />
         </service>
         <channels>
            <channel ref="http" port="123456" />
         </channels>
      </application>
   </system.runtime.remoting>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
   </startup>